# Selecting MySQL query via PHP variables

Tags: php, mysql, variables, mysql-num-rows

I am getting zero in `$booked_num`, I tried the query in SQL with values in place of variables, it worked fine. But I don't know where I am making a mistake, please help.
I already echoed every variable and everything is fine, but nothing is there in `$booked_row`and `$booked_num` is echoing zero.

```
require_once 'mysql_connector.php';
$booked_result = mysql_query('select * from booked where train_no = ".$train_no." and date = ".$date." and st_from = ".$st_from." and st_to = ".$st_to.";') or die(mysql_error()) ;
$booked_num = mysql_num_rows($booked_result);
echo $booked_num;
$booked_row = mysql_fetch_array($booked_result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
print_r($booked_row);
```

Comment: You're mixing single and double quotes. You cannot start a string with a single quote and end it with a double quote.

Comment: I'd avoid using `mysql_*` functions, as of `PHP 5.5.0` they are deprecated. You should considering using [`mysqli` or `PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$booked_result = mysql_query('select * from booked where train_no = ".$train_no." and date = ".$date." and st_from = ".$st_from." and st_to = ".$st_to.";') or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

This syntax is incorrect - you need to close the string before concatenating variables.
Something like:

```
$booked_result = mysql_query('select * from booked where train_no = "' .$train_no. '" and date = "' .$date. '" and st_from = "' .$st_from. '" and st_to = "' .$st_to. '";') or die(mysql_error());
```

Also, you should consider switching to the PDO library.  Among other things, it will help you avoid sql injection attacks in your queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SamDufel !!
Actually have to make a project on Railway Reservation and literally fed up of working since last two days. Could anybody please help me with the concepts of these quotes in sql_query and php script?
Thanks again ! :)

Comment: @code.atodi Read the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single and here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double . Also, **DO NOT** use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, use `mysqli_*` or PDO.

Comment: @code.atodi - the php manual page on strings has some nice examples, and a thorough overview of features.  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php  If there's anything specific you're not understanding, you can post another question about it.  Also, I highly recommend you use an editor with syntax highlighting - it will make it much easier to see if you're quoting something incorrectly.

Comment: @SamDufel I use notepad++, that's basic and fast.
And thanks both of you for the links ! :)