# Ajax to php and store in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hello I am having a problem

I am sending a javascript variable to my php script and attemping to store that variable in mysql db but it just does not work.

Here is my code:

js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var myData = "Hello";

        function AJAXAction () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.php',
                data: { myPhpData: myData },
               success: function (response) {
                alert (response);
               }
            }); 
        }

        AJAXAction();
    </script>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","testt") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
function goDoIt ($link) {
    $why = $_GET['myPhpData'];  
    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (id) VALUES '$why'";
    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    echo "booooom";
}
goDoIt ($link);     
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The result alerts "boooom" but it does not store my $why variable in my table

Comment: I smell SQL injection vulnerabilities.. Use prepared statements!

Comment: And add error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable should be enclosed in {} plus you need to enclose it in ()

```
  $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (id) VALUES ('{$why}')";
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however I have never needed to do this before hand when inserting values into a table? why is this?

Comment: @Joe I am not very sure why the other way around it was not working. there are several ways to evaluate the variable. You can concat the string also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001001/selecting-mysql-query-via-php-variables

Answer (score 2):

Try it:

```
$why = $_GET['myPhpData'];  
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (id) VALUES '$why'";
if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
   echo "booooom";
}else{
   echo "error";
}
```

Then you can get if the query is correct or not.

Comment: I'd upvote for the error handling, but the obvious sql injection kind of ruins the answer.

Comment: Sure, you can add some function that prevents SQL Injection, I just wanted to show a way to cath the error

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (id) VALUES ('".$why."');
```

you can also do this

Comment: Still vulnerable to SQL injection. What if I pass `'); DROP TABLE test_table; --` in `$why`?